# Convert specific char array range to string

Tags: c

I'm writing some simple C code whereby I've received a data packet which I then place in a char array. I intend on converting a specific range of elements specifically elements 16 to 31 to a string.

I understand strncpy can be used but this is in cases where you know the exact content of the array and the "string"/set of characters you need to copy from the array.

In my case the elements of the array (see array in my code below titled analysis_buffer) are randomly generated but I'm sure that elements 6 to 9 will always contain digits which is is the range of the array I desire to convert into a string.

Below is my code and below the code are the contents of the node_EUI[j] array:

```
int j,  ANALYSIS_BUFFER_SIZE = 16;
char node_EUI[ANALYSIS_BUFFER_SIZE];
char analysis_buffer[ANALYSIS_BUFFER_SIZE];

//
void convertspecificarrayelements();

// 
void convertspecificarrayelements() {

    // 
    for (j = 0; j < ANALYSIS_BUFFER_SIZE; j++) {

        // 
        node_EUI[j] = analysis_buffer[j];

        // 
        printf("node_EUI[%u]: %c\n", j, node_EUI[j]);
    }

    // Here I would like to convert elements 6 to 9 of the node_EUI[j] array to a string as I need the 
    // digits for a specific purpose

}

// 
int main() {

    analysis_buffer[0] = 'Q';
    analysis_buffer[1] = 'W';
    analysis_buffer[2] = 'E';
    analysis_buffer[3] = 'R';
    analysis_buffer[4] = 'T';
    analysis_buffer[5] = 'Y';
    analysis_buffer[6] = '1';
    analysis_buffer[7] = '2';
    analysis_buffer[8] = '3;
    analysis_buffer[9] = '4';
    analysis_buffer[10] = 'Q';
    analysis_buffer[11] = 'W';
    analysis_buffer[12] = 'E';
    analysis_buffer[13] = 'R';
    analysis_buffer[14] = 'T';
    analysis_buffer[15] = 'Y';

    // 
    convertspecificarrayelements();

}
```

Any ideas on how I would like to convert elements 6 to 9 of the node_EUI[j] array to a string as I need the digits for a specific purpose?

Regards - Alex.

Answer (score 1):

If you are totally sure about the offset and length always being valid, just use `memcpy()`:

```
char number[8];

memcpy(number, node_EUI + 9, 4);
number[4] = '\0';
```

The above is optimized for clarity. Many compilers will optimize out the call to `memcpy()`, but it's a decent way to clearly express "four characters are copied". The final line terminates `number` after four characters, making sure it's a valid string.

You could prettify it to "hide" the magic numbers.